# Disable the default jQueryMobile error loading page message

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

is is possible to just disable the "error loading page" message in jQueryMobile? i have the following in my head and a) the message still shows up. b) the text isn't correct

```
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessage = 'coming right up!';
});
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessage = true;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

By handling jQuery Mobile's 'mobileinit' event you can suppress the error message from displaying. To handle the 'mobileinit' event, create a file, **custom-script.js** like this:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.extend(  $.mobile , {
      pageLoadErrorMessage: ""
  });
  alert("mobileinit received");
});
```

Then reference the file **BEFORE** your jQuery Mobile script tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='libs/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/custom-script.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="libs/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

That's all it takes to suppress the message.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it with css, like this:

```
div.ui-loader.ui-overlay-shadow { display: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html

See pageLoadErrorMessage area

Hopefully, if you set it to blank, the page wont show.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to target the Error message but not the default loading widget icon

```
.ui-loader.ui-body-e { left:-9999px;}
```

You can trigger it to display to inspect the css like so

```
$(".ui-loader").show()
```

There is a known iOS bug where you get this for ajax calls that succeed (they return 0 instead of 200 apparently)